# Use jQuery to check if links still work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404

I made a quick function to check every link on the page using AJAX to see if they still work. This seems to be working, but it's adding the success and error class to every one. How can I get the error callback function to only throw if the AJAX response is 404?

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).children('a').each(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr('src'),
            success:$(this).addClass('success'),
            error:$(this).addClass('error')
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `success` and `error` parameters expect functions.

You'd need to wrap the code in an anonymous function:

```
//there's no need to complicate things, use one call to each()
$('li > a').each(function () {
    var $this;
    $this = $(this); //retain a reference to the current link
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr('href'), //be sure to check the right attribute
        success: function () { //pass an anonymous callback function
            $this.addClass('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, er) {
            //only set the error on 404
            if (jqXHR.status === 404) { 
                $this.addClass('error');
            }
            //you could perform additional checking with different classes
            //for other 400 and 500 level HTTP status codes.
        }
    });
});
```

Otherwise, you're just setting `success` to the return value of `$(this).addClass('success');`, which is just a jQuery collection.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having a weird issue though where they'll respond with 200 but still throw an error, as they are red in Firefox's console. Might you have any idea why this might be? Here's a link:

http://testwww.chicagobooth.edu/links_test.html

Comment: You can't make cross-domain requests unless you're using a JSONP request. It's a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue. Additionally, you should use `console.log` instead of `alert`, and review messages in your JavaScript console.

Comment: Yeah I usually do use console.log I was just doing things quickly to sort out this issue lol. Let me look into JSONP now.

Comment: JSONP isn't going to do what I think you want it to do. You can't scrape HTML pages with it. It's meant for interacting with JSON data on a different server.

Comment: Oh I figured as much, I'm scraping this idea all together though lol. Thanks for the insight though!

Answer (score 1):

First you need a success and failed handler, now the code just runs for every link. 
You don't need the src attribute, but the href prop.

This should work:

```
$('li').each(function(){
   $(this).children('a').each(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).prop('href'),
        success:function(){$(this).addClass('success')},
        error:function(){$(this).addClass('error')}
    })
  })
});
```

I also find it more elegant to use index and value in the each loop, so:

```
$('li').each(function(){
   $(this).children('a').each(function(index,value){
    $.ajax({
        url:$(value).prop('href'),
        success:function(){$(value).addClass('success')},
        error:function(){$(value).addClass('error')}
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Cool, never heard of "prop" before... nice! +1

Comment: @andrux, if you don't know what methods are available in jQuery, then you should [review the api](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks for the comment, but a "review" wouldn't mean I would know ALL the methods available in jQuery, unless I really had that kind of time available - which I don't

Comment: @zzzzBov I get your point, thanks for the comment, droping out of this comment thread

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your success and error callbacks inside a `function()` call:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).children('a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url:$this.attr('href'),
            success: function() {
                $this.addClass('success');
            },
            error: function() {
                $this.addClass('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers add the class for ALL errors, if you truly want it for a `404` only then this should do:

```
$(this).children('a').each(function(){
    var self;
    self = this; //retain a reference to this
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr('src'),
        success: function () { //pass an anonymous callback function
            $(self).addClass('success');
        },
        statusCode: {
           404: function() {
              $this.addClass('error');
           }
        }
    });
});
```