# In HTML i kept button to download some file its working but in that path if that file is not exists then i need to show message?

Tags: jquery, html

This Code i written to download a resume : Inside a button

```
onclick="window.location.href='/Uploads/Resume/1.docx'"
```

The file is downloading but if file not found in that path then i have to show a message Like file is not Found How can I do this

Comment: An advanced UI design should be to disable the button after checking if the link is live or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310029/use-jquery-to-check-if-links-still-work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Your web browser will already do that, as it does for any web path that returns a `404` error.

So simply let that mechanism do its job.

Comment: But file not found message i need to show  alert message in the same page without redirecting to that particular path..

Comment: @user2955331: Then you'll have to encapsulate all of this in a function that first checks, via AJAX, whether the file can be downloaded. It gets complicated. Why?

Comment: In our project i need to do this task..i am not having idea to show that alert message...

Comment: @user2955331: I'm asking _why_. Also I just gave some ideas.